# why the default (ambiance) theme is not changing on my machine?

Tags: themes

I use the "Ambiance(default)" theme.

I modified this file:
`/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/index.theme`

From this line:
`ButtonLayout=close,minimize,maximize:`

To this one:
`ButtonLayout=minimize,maximize,close:`

And rebooted the machine, but all windows layout are still `close,minimize,maximize`.

PS.:
I did backup the Ambiance folder before doing it.

Why did I do it like that? Because every other instructions from anywhere I try them are not working **for me**, from copying the theme to my user's home folder (and renaming things), to making a root copy at /usr/share/themes/ as a new theme (renaming things too), and everything else... and I don't know why!
So this SHOULD work, as I am changing the core theme itself, but it still doesn't!!!
What is wrong with my system?

ubuntu 16.04.

related:
[How to edit and install pre-installed Ambiance theme without unity tweak tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823808/how-to-edit-and-install-pre-installed-ambiance-theme-without-unity-tweak-tool?rq=1)